# Using delayed_jobs gem in model on a method without a definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, paperclip, delayed-job

I have recently added the ability to upload PDFs on my website, and in uploading them I convert them to different sized jpg using the paperclip gem

```
  has_attached_file :pdf, styles: { :thumb => ["100x100#", :jpg], :medium => ["300x300#", :jpg], :large => ["500x500#", :jpg]}
```

But this seems to take up a lot of time in the conversion process, so I am looking into the delayed_jobs gem, but because this function call is not wrapped within a definition (which looks like it is required for delayed_job), I cant seem to find an answer as to how to delay the converting process of paperclip as so to not have the website hang on the page as it converts.

Is there a simple answer to this?

Comment: Anyone have an idea?